How to bypass cloudflare in selenium webdriver python
I can’t bypass cloudflare protection in selenium webdriver (I am using chrome webdriver).
The protection page contains only a checkbox, that says “verify that you are human”, there is no complex captcha or anything. And it doesn’t work even when I click the checkbox manually.
It’s really weird because I can easily do it in my main browser.
I have enabled this option:
--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled
It didn’t help.
Even tried some other options:
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
And it still didn’t work.
I suppose there must be some option in selenium chrome driver that should solve this problem.
Or can it be because my chrome version is too old?
Upd: I am trying to solve this using seleniumbase, but it doesn’t help. It appears that this is because I am using it with metamask extension and it overrides the UC mode
from seleniumbase import SB 
...
with SB(uc=True, incognito=True, proxy=proxy, agent=agent, extension_dir='metamask-chrome-11.16.3') as sb: 
    ...
    # the code fore bypassing cloudflare: 
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 3) 
    sb.driver.switch_to_frame('iframe') 
    sb.uc_click('#challenge-stage > div > label > input[type=checkbosx]', reconnect_time=4) 
...

Proxy is in the format: user:password@ip:port
Upd2:
I have tried using seleniumwire undetected mode, seleniumbase, undetected chrome driver, none of these options worked.
Also I tried editing the chrome driver file with hexeditor to remove the console variables that have cdc (I tried to do that because I found out that cloudflare looks for them to see if you’re a bot) in them, but then selenium can’t gives win32 api error

The click-the-box captcha has nothing to do with actual clicking of the box.  It is tracking your cursor movement on the way to the box.  If your cursor movement is human-like, you are good.  Using selenium does not display a human-like behaviour.

It doesn’t work even when I click the box manually, so I don’t think that is the case

Regular Selenium gets detected when hitting a Cloudflare-protected site, but you can use something such as SeleniumBase UC Mode to bypass CAPTCHA screens. Here's an example after pip install seleniumbase and running with python:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, test=True) as sb:
    url = "https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in"
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 3)
    if not sb.is_text_visible("Username", '[for="user_login"]'):
        sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 4)
    sb.assert_text("Username", '[for="user_login"]', timeout=3)

That's for a common CF-protected site when you don't have to click a checkbox at all if they think you're a human. There are different types of Cloudflare CAPTCHAs (such as ones that everyone must click, or ones that appear after performing some other action, such as clicking a button).
Here's an example of a site where the CF CAPTCHA only appears after performing another action first. The CAPTCHA is bypassed with the uc_click(selector) method:
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB(uc=True, test=True, locale_code="en") as sb:
    url = "https://ahrefs.com/website-authority-checker"
    input_field = 'input[placeholder="Enter domain"]'
    submit_button = 'span:contains("Check Authority")'
    sb.driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 1)  # The bot-check is later
    sb.type(input_field, "github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase")
    sb.driver.reconnect(0.1)
    sb.driver.uc_click(submit_button, reconnect_time=4)
    sb.wait_for_text_not_visible("Checking", timeout=10)
    sb.highlight('p:contains("github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase")')
    sb.highlight('a:contains("Top 100 backlinks")')
    sb.set_messenger_theme(location="bottom_center")
    sb.post_message("SeleniumBase wasn't detected!")


Is there a way to integrate the normal selenium webdriver into SB class? Can I, for example, initialize the instance of SB from selenium webdriver object?
Like this:
sb = SB(uc=True, driver=my_selenium_driver)

The normal chromedriver sets Chrome DevTools Console variables that immediately make it detected. UC Mode creates a modified chromedriver called uc_driver to prevent that. UC Mode also has special methods that won't get detected like regular Selenium methods.

I have tested it in my code, it still doesn’t work. It throws TimeOutException or NoSuchElement, when I try to click the checkbox using selenium or seleniumbase. It looks like it can’t find the checkbox, although I have tried it with both selector and  xpath and I am confident that xpath and selector were correct.
And, as earlier, it doesn’t work when I click the checkbox manually neither.
I have also tested the code you gave in the example and the problem is same there.
Already tried it on different devices, it doesn’t work on neither of them

CF checkboxes are in iframes. You have to switch into the frame first before interacting with any element in there. CF looks for webdriver variables in the console to detect you (it doesn't care how you actually click something... that's why you'll still get detected on manual clicks in Selenium-controled browsers unless you use frameworks like SeleniumBase UC Mode to prevent that).

That is exactly the point. I am using seleniumbase with UC mode and I get detected on manual clicks

To remain undetected while performing manual actions in UC Mode, open the URL with a special breakpoint: driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, "breakpoint"). Replace url with the URL you want.

Performing manual actions during the UC Mode special breakpoint is covered here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pTpBtaE7SQ&t=1196s

Nope, doesn’t work with this option as well.
Could you please elaborate on what console variables cloudflare is looking for? Is there another to remove them?

That's all answered with great detail in the UC Mode video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pTpBtaE7SQ

Hey, is it possible that problems occur because I am using proxy? Because I'm having same issues even with the code from your example

Maybe. How are you setting the proxy? SeleniumBase has a proxy arg, but the examples I posted aren't setting it.

I have edited my initial question and added the code there. Also, fyi, I am switching between tabs before I run that part of the code and also I am using an extension and a custom user agent

One: Don't change the user agent. SeleniumBase automatically gives you the optimal one based on your settings. Two: That specific extension has been known to override UC Mode settings, causing it to stop working. Skip those two things.

I can’t do this project without metamask extension though

That piece of information wasn't included in your original question. You edited the question after Stack Overflow admins marked it as closed, which means this thread is no longer accepting new answers.

I appreciate your help, but still my problem isn’t fixed though. This is really important for me. Can you please tell me how exactly metamask overrides UC mode? Then I could edit the metamask source code so that it wouldn’t cause any trouble. And btw if it’s more convenient for you to discuss this in dm, you can give me your contacts
